# I am getting error while I am creating app in npm

Tags: node.js, reactjs

PS C:\ReactJS> npx create-react-app my-app
node:fs:1398
handleErrorFromBinding(ctx);
^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'my-app'
at Object.mkdirSync (node:fs:1398:3)
at module.exports.makeDirSync (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\make-dir.js:23:13)
at createApp (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:257:6)
at C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:223:9
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
errno: -4048,
syscall: 'mkdir',
code: 'EPERM',
path: 'my-app'
}

Node.js v18.17.1

I am expecting to create the app

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.